# “You must pass in a non null View” when getting profile picture from firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

The app give me an error when i tried to load uploaded image into the nav header in my Homepage.

error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.cqaai.tutorpal, PID: 23741 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:685)
at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:457)
at com.example.cqaai.tutorpal.activity.HomeActivity$3.onDataChange(HomeActivity.java:199)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)                                                                                
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)                                                                                
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6097)                                                                                
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)                                                                                   
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

the last if statement is the cause of the error:

```
private void getUserInfo() {
    mTuteeDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()>0){
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

                if(map.get("FullName")!=null){
                    mFullName = map.get("FullName").toString();
                    txtFullName.setText(mFullName);
                }

                if(map.get("UserName")!=null) {
                    mUserName = map.get("UserName").toString();
                    txtUserName.setText("@" + mUserName);
                }

                if(map.get("profileImageUrl")!=null){
                    mProfileImageUrl = map.get("profileImageUrl").toString();
                    Glide.with(getApplication()).load(mProfileImageUrl).into(mProfileImage);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

I added additional links in `gist.github` just incase. which contains the related `xml` and database structure. Forgive me if I ask question in the wrong way..

[complete codings: `HomeActivity.java`, `activity_home`, etc here](https://gist.github.com/ainulfi3/00e3633a9dbb2689f25e650a99850a56)

Answer (score 0):

Your `mProfileImage` is `null`. 
Change :

```
 mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
```

To :

```
 mProfileImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
```

Comment: hi i changed it already, your fix solution is correct because of my silly mistakes typing the ID . but it still give me the same error at com.example.cqaai.tutorpal.activity.HomeActivity$3.onDataChange(HomeActivity.java:199)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)

Comment: caused by the same error as stated @ my post above, the error came from the line which i use Glide for this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
final View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
final ImageView mProfileImage = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.image);
```